# How to select a radio button via link reference

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let say I have 2 webpages A and B. On webpage A I have this tag

```
<a href="B.php?var=$somevalue"> Go to B </a>
```

On webpages B, I a list of radio buttons

```
        <div class="tabGroup">
        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view1" class="tab1" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="view1">View 1</label>

        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view2" class="tab2"/>
        <label for="view2">View 2</label>

        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view3" class="tab3"/>
        <label for="view3">View 3</label>
        </div>
```

So the default selected radio button is ""view1" cause it is "checked". But what I want is that the link reference can check the radio button "view2" or "view3" for me depend on the $var I pass through URL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What value does the `var` contain? `view1`, `view2`, `view3`?

Comment: It can contain integer value like : 1, 2, 3 so you can use that to go to corresponding input on page B . Actually, whatever value you want that is convenient to you

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not the best way, but its pretty simple one if you have only 3 inputs:

```
    <div class="tabGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view1" class="tab1" <?php  if($_GET['var'] == 'view1') {echo 'checked="checked"'}?> />
    <label for="view1">View 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view2" class="tab2" <?php  if($_GET['var'] == 'view2') {echo 'checked="checked"'}?> />
    <label for="view2">View 2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="view3" class="tab3" <?php  if($_GET['var'] == 'view3') {echo 'checked="checked"'}?> />
    <label for="view3">View 3</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: how about the defaut "checked" .I still want that . Will it make view1 as a defaut ?

Comment: check the other answer, its long, but its alot better

Answer (score 0):

I think these codes should do what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get current url
    var href = location.href;

    // get the variable value
    var id_value = href.split('?var=')[1];

    // make the radio button checked
    $('#' + id_value).prop('checked', true);
})
```

But i think a little improvement can make it more beautiful.

You should give each radio tag one value.

```
    <div class="tabGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" value="1" id="view1" class="tab1" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="view1">View 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" value="2" id="view2" class="tab2"/>
    <label for="view2">View 2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" value="3" id="view3" class="tab3"/>
    <label for="view3">View 3</label>
    </div>
```

then use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get current url
    var href = location.href;

    // get the variable value
    var checked_radio_value = href.split('?var=')[1];

    // make the radio button checked
    $('input[name="tabGroup1"][value="' + checked_radio_value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
})
```